# snowflake get numeric values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hi I have one dobubt in snowflake.
how to get only numeric value and only charter values based on columns in snow flake server

```
source tablle  product
Pid   
1     
2r    
31u   
ure4k 
8   

based on above data I want output like below : 
source tablle 
Pid   
1     
8  

source tablle  product
Pname   
1e     
2r    
31u   
urek 
re
based on above data i want output like below 

pname 
urek
re
 


I have tried like below  to get only numeric values
select * from product  where pid not like'%[a-zA-Z]%'

I have tried like below  to get only numeric values
select * from product  where pid not like'%[0-9]%'
```

above two queryied not given excepted result
could you please tell me how to write query to achive this task in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

You can use try_to_numeric() and rlike:

```
-- Get only numeric rows
with T1 as
(
    select COLUMN1 as PID  from (values ('1'), ('2r'), ('31u'), ('ure4k'), ('8'))
)
select * from T1 where try_to_numeric(PID) is not null
;
```

Output:

| PID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 8 |

```
-- Get rows that have no numbers 
with T1 as
(
    select COLUMN1 as PNAME  from (values ('1e'), ('2r'), ('31u'), ('urek'), ('re'))
)
select * from T1 where PNAME rlike '^([^0-9]*)$'
;
```

Output:

| PNAME |
| --- |
| urek |
| re |